# Split numbers and letters from string with regular expression

Tags: java, regex, string, split

I have the following regex:

```
String regx = "\\d{2}\\w{3}";
```

It says, two numeric and three alphanumeric chars in string. I want to split String by using above regex.

Example:

```
String stringToSplit = "99E0L";
```

Output will be

> 99
>   E0L

Is it possible to split above String using above regex in Java? What API should I use to do it?

Comment: Why don't you try and tell us ?

Comment: @Tom It didn’t say that. I improved an edit suggestion.

Comment: Now, it is `string.split("(?<=\\d)(?=\\D)|(?<=\\D)(?=\\d)");`

Comment: @Tom I did not get any notification.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Capturing* instead of *splitting* should be your obvious choice. But if you want to split, then you can use *zero-width* assertions.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String stringToSplit = "99E0L";
    String[] arr = stringToSplit.split("(?<=\\G\\d{2})");
    for (String s : arr) {
        System.out.println(s);
    }
}
```

O/P:

> 99
>   E0L

Comment: You have used different regx. Did you mean with my regx it is not possible and I have to use different one

Comment: @sillyquestions - You can use your regex with `Pattern` and `Matcher` to capture Strings but not *split* them.

Comment: Thank you for comment. I thought it might have possible in java. Thats all what I want to know. :)

Comment: @sillyquestions - You should not use this approach. You should use `Pattern` and `Matcher` with your regex (with capturing groups) :P

Comment: Just as a note, when you want to create a line break, then either use two spaces `"  "` or `<br>`. The quote block formatting looks a bit better with that :D.